# Using shared drive from web portal for storage/ sharing

Tags: windows, web, architecture

We have a client requirement to open up share "Share drive" path for specific set of users in client's network. I have few questions:-

Opening up a network drive from web portal, Is this approach good enough for document storage/sharing? What are the concerns to share with client before agree to this approach?

Client have limited budget & can't afford a document uploader module.

Any thoughts on this?

Target operating system in Windows.

Comment: Dear anonymous("who down voted"), Could you please list out reason as well?

Answer (score 0):

The only concern I would have is the unmitigated terror involved in leaving SMB exposed on the public internet.  Akin to leaving my (hypothetical) Mercedes sitting unlocked in a bad part of town, with the keys in the ignition.

I would propose two alternatives that are less terrifying:

1. use Remote Desktop to allow the client to map their local drives, and thus transfer files a little bit more safely (opening a firewall hole for RDP protocol)
2. use a VPN to allow the customer to securely connect to your network, and then expose SMB there
3. Do #1 & #2 together (VPN + RDP)